# What is the value of maxvalue in partition

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning, database-partitioning

How can I know the exact value of maxvalue in high_value in partition?

```
PARTITION "PARTMAXVALUE" VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
```

Also if the table has already a partition created where high value is set to maxvalue, will I still able to create other partitions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

From Oracle docs:

> MAXVALUE represents a virtual infinite value that sorts higher than
>   any other possible value for the partitioning key, including the NULL
>   value.

To find the upper value in a partition you can run:

```
select table_owner, table_name, partition_name, high_value
from all_tab_partitions;
```

If there is a "max_value" partition in a range partitioned table, you won't be able to add partitions until you drop that partition.

(You can save all the information contained in the maxvalue partition in another table(a copy_table), drop the problem-partition, create desired partitions, and then reinsert from copy-table.)

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to create new partition, but you will be able to split MAXVALUE partition at any value you like.

Comment: nice ideea. I'll give you +1 if you share an example or the syntax.